# Include node_modules while publish in VS2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio-2017, node-modules

I have a working ASP.NET MVC app with Angular 6 front-end. I have configured VS2017 to build and run the app without any problems. Is there any way I can include the node_modules folder while publish and prevent it from downloading the NPM packages while publishing?

I'm in need of help because I'm the first to work with Angular in my workplace. Any help or a nudge towards the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing MVC with Angular 6 also!

May I clarify where you're publishing to?

Possibly you could be able to publish if you show all files in the solution explorer and include the node_modules folder into your project?

And if you're developing in the Angular front end, I highly recommend using `ng serve` from the app folder, as each save re-compiles instantly without having to close the Visual studio debug and start it again.

Hope I helped :)